# Android Bluetooth Server Client Application

Tags: android, bluetooth, client-server

I am trying to write server client bluetooth application for Android phones. I am also referring to BluetoothChat sample code that is present in SDK.

Aplication "Server" will be sending some data to application "Client" via bluetooth connection. Now without any intervention by user at client side, I want to handle this data in my Client Service and perform some task over it. My question is how to let Client service know that the data received over Bluetooth was for this service and handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the code for BluetoothChat application, its having a unique UUID to listen for accepting incoming connection and for making a outgoing connection. This UUID is same for both incoming/outgoing connections.
MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");